# how to give image fade effect on hover?

Tags: html, css

How to make fade hover change on a parent div when we hover over a child div?
I want the hover to have a fade effect and change the background image of the parent div. The change is happening very fast. I want the change to happen and slowly and smoothly.

```js
<script>
  $('#hoverdiv').on('mouseover', function(){
  $(this).parent().addClass('is-hover');
}).on('mouseout', function(){
  $(this).parent().removeClass('is-hover');
})
 </script>
```

```css
.bground {
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  background: url(../img/bg1.jpg) no-repeat top center;
}

.bground:after {
 content: url(../img/bg2.jpg);
 width:0;
 height:0;
 display:none;
}

.is-hover {
  background: url(../img/bg2.jpg) no-repeat top center;
}

#hoverdiv
{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0;
}
```

```html
<section id="bground" class="bground">
  <div id="hoverdiv">
  <div class="display">
    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo">
  </div>
  <div class="page-scroll">
    <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle" style="color:#000000">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: with the above js i am able to change the parent div with the help of the child div. i am just not able to make any desired transitions. how to do that would be helpful

Answer (score 3):

You are adding and removing class with js which cannot be slow down.

What you can do is add transition in css

```
.is-hover {
  background: url(../img/bg2.jpg) no-repeat top center;
  transition:all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  -moz-transition:all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  -ms-transition:all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  -o-transition:all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition:all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
```

It is important to add prefix like `-moz-`, `-webkit-` etc to let it work in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks mate. But working in Chrome, not in Firefox. I added all the above lines as u mentioned.

Comment: are you sure?? could you create a fiddle for it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for javascript. You can easily achieve this with css transitions:

```css
.bground {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #aaa url("http://placehold.it/300x200/ffff00") no-repeat top center;
  position: relative;
}

.bground:after {
  content: "";
  background: url("http://placehold.it/300x200/ff0000") no-repeat top center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.bground:hover:after {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bground"></div>
```

Comment: yes but I want to hover on the particular area of #hoverdiv to change .bground's background image

Answer (score 1):

```css
.bground {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #aaa url("http://placehold.it/300x200/ffff00") no-repeat top center;
  position: relative;
}

.bground:after {
  content: "";
  background: url("http://placehold.it/300x200/ff0000") no-repeat top center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s linear 0s;
}

.bground:hover:after {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="bground"></div>
```

Comment: this is just a duplicate of my answer